# Ionic2 how to set image background color?

Tags: background, ionic2

[image]

This is my image which background color is transparent, and I dont want use ionic2 default color, I want to change default color to red, what should I do.

When I following this one [enter link description here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/change-background-color-of-ion-content/52868/2) 
It will be showing like this
[image]

And I want to change whole background color not only the image background color!!!

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/change-background-color-of-ion-content/52868/2

Comment: @seesharper This one I check ald.. But this one can only change image background color , not whole default background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change or add default color in `variables.scss`

```
$colors: ( primary: #ff0000, secondary: #32db64, danger: #f53d3d, light: #f4f4f4, dark: #222);
```

For full background color try this-

In page.scss -

```
 .masters .scroll-content {
      background-color: color($colors, primary) !important; // or  background-color: red !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the info on theming an Ionic app: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/theming-your-app/
Note the `base` property in the $colors map...